# How to remove weird border on JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a JTextArea, a Jlist and a couple other things on my JPanel, The JTextArea seems to be putting this weird border around the right and bottom side of the TextArea.

I tried using `textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2));` To get rid of it

That adds the black border as expected but I still get the weird border.
Here is a picture.

[image: Weird Border]

[image: Weird Border 2]

I can't seem to remove the white and gray border by the textarea

I have a Border Layout with a 5 pixel gap vertically, and horizontally.

**Edit**
I don't think I stated this correctly, The white and grey "borders" are there even when I don't add the `.setBorder()`

Comment: it does not seem a border... maybe overlapped `JList` and `JText` ?

Comment: @JordiCastilla I have a border layout with a 5 pixel gap. Don't think it's overlapping. Better image posted.

Comment: the problem is the *white line*?

Comment: The white and grey line.

Comment: actually does not seem strange for me... you tried changing position of `JList` and is not the problem?  Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html

Comment: I have tried changing the fixed cell width, and height on the list and tried moving the position. No luck. :/

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Is that border different from the borders of other Swing text input controls?  I believe that appearance is determined by the Swing look and feel.

Comment: how do you separate your components? are you using a `JSplitPane`?

Comment: @VGR The white and grey borders are there no matter if the `.setBorder` is on and I've tried different L&F's. No luck.

Comment: I have reproduce your case, and I guess is part of the metal look and feel

Comment: @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz I use the border layout with 5 pixel gaps in both directions. `mPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));` The text area is `BorderLayout.CENTER` and JList is `BorderLayout.LINE_END`

Comment: @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz Hmm, I'm currently using Synth and a XML file as my look and feel. I'll try changing up my L&F's a couple more times.

Comment: are you using your jtextareas inside a jscrollpane?

Comment: @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz I do have a scrollpane set AS_NEEDED, When the scrollbar is needed the little "border" is still there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are seeing the border of both your `JTextArea` and `JScrollPane`, try remove the border of your scrollpane, something like the following code:

```
jScrollPane1.setBorder(null);
```

Will get you from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Note how the white line has disappeared only from the `JTextArea`. Is this what are you looking for?

Comment: Ahhh! That would do it. Thank you so much. :D Didn't really consider this seen as the scrollbar is hidden most of the time.